# Why not hand when hovering link(<a>)?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, sliding-doors

**Hi,**

I know that its possible to set the cusor to hand when hovering an object like this:

```
CSS :

cursor:             hand;
cursor:             pointer;
```

This should be done automaticly with a link element that looks like this :

```
<a onclick="" class="btn1">
  <span>Sök</span>
</a>
```

But In my case its not?

With firebug I can see that the followin CSS is applyed

```
<a> element
a.btn1 {
    background: url("Images/Menus/bg_button_a.gif") no-repeat scroll right top transparent;
    color: #444444;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font: 12px arial,sans-serif;
    height: 24px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    padding-right: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    font-family: Arial,Verdana,serif;
    font-size: 0.81em;
}
```

And

```
SPAN element
    a.btn1 span {
        background: url("Images/Menus/bg_button_span.gif") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
        display: block;
        line-height: 14px;
        padding: 5px 0 5px 18px;
    }
    Controls.css (rad 80)
    * {
        margin: 0;
    }

    a.btn1 {
        color: #444444;
        font: 12px arial,sans-serif;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    body {
        font-family: Arial,Verdana,serif;
        font-size: 0.81em;
    }
```

How can I track down this problem?

**BestRegards**

Comment: Why do you have the span in there in the first place? If it isn't specifying a style class or being identified by an id for javascript, it seems fairly unnecessary, and it may be causing the element to be interpreted differently by the browser.

Comment: You are right, in my case I dont want to link to a page, instead I will run javascript on click. The grate thing with a element is that I easly can use active, hover for css. But you mean that I should use a span instead and then add the onmouseover, onmouseout, mousedown, mouseup attributes ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The hand appears only if the ANCHOR has a `href` attribute set.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/KAEbR/

Comment: to add to this, you should specify a href like `#btn1` (ideally the name of the action being performed) to give you some history control on the events.

Comment: @zzzz My approach would be to just set href="#" and then disable the anchors via preventDefault().

Comment: Vidas, I do that too, but I really love the idea of the browser back button being easily converted into `undo` with the creative use of the `hashchange` event.

Answer (score 6):

It's likely because your  doesn't have a "href" value, you could change it to

```
<a href="#" onclick="" class="btn1"/>
```

You can also add the following css to force the hand to always appear for links:

```
a{ cursor: pointer;}
```

Answer (score 3):

Without the `href` attribute the `a` tag does not declare a hyperlink. If it possesses a `name` or `id` attribute, it may declare the *destination* of a hyperlink instead. (http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#anchors-with-id)

If the element you want to declare has no semantic resemblance to a hyperlink and you are relying on CSS to make it appear like one, why bother? You might just as well use any old `span`.

What you should **not** do is write `a { cursor:pointer; }` into your CSS, causing any `a` elements to display a hand on hover, even those that are not hyperlinks. Instead you should add a `href` attribute like has been suggested. As a value you could enter `#` if there is no non-JavaScript functionality to fall back on. Otherwise you should enter the URI of the resource you want to link to.

See also Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Anchor

Comment: You are right, in my case I dont want to link to a page, instead I will run javascript on click. The grate thing with a element is that I easly can use active, hover for css. But you mean that I should use a span instead and then add the onmouseover, onmouseout, mousedown, mouseup attributes ?

Comment: No, you should probably add a `href` attribute. Is there an actual URL you want to reference?

Comment: No, this will not a real link, It will submit a form with javascript. is a regular a element with href=# still correct way to go? Or should I go with a span and then use onmouseover, onmouseout, mousedown, mouseup attributes?

Comment: Well, if you want to submit a form, you should probably use a submit button and style it according to your needs. Is this for a website or some kind of JavaScript application (e.g. for Mac OS X's Dashboard or a mobile plattform)?

Comment: If it is part of a "normal" website, you should most probably use a submit button, so that users without JavaScript can perform a search as well. If not and you don't want to use a button element for some reason, I would go with an `a` element with `href="#"`.

Comment: Here's an example of styling a submit button in *link manner*: http://jsfiddle.net/D5QvG/

Comment: Its alot of talk about supporting no javascript? Do not all "modern" sites use javascript? Yes I know that the cawlers do not handle it but there is ways of solving this.

Comment: It is true that today JavaScript can be expected in most clients. When designing web pages, though, it is good practice to make sites a accessible and universally usable, as sensibly viable. When you make use of standard elements for the respective functions, users with unusual setups will have a better chance at using your website. You could consider, for example, blind or otherwise handicapped users browsing with a screen reader. If you unnecessarily route around standard elements you lose the benefit of having adequate UI in different user agents "for free".

Answer (score 2):

That's not a link.  Links have `href` attributes.  That's just an anchor that runs JavaScript when clicked.